# Installing Xpather for Firefox 10

Tags: firefox-addon, xpi, forward-compatibility, firefox-10

I want to use [Xpather](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/xpather/) with Firefox 10. When I try to install it, Firefox says Xpather could not be installed as it is not compatible.

Answer (score 0):

You can redefine the Firefox version compatibility as in an [unrelated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442844/updating-my-firefox-extension-autoupdates-not-working). Use the [Addon Compatibility Reporter](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/add-on-compatibility-reporter/) or open a thread on the [Mozilla support forum](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/new) to report this.